# Python3 /Django Using Multiprocessing to Build a Common List

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, multiprocessing

## The Problem:

Let's say I'm throwing an enormous party. Gatsby style. I have asked a pizza place for a boatload of random pizzas to be delivered to my address.

Once they arrive, I need to identify all of the non-vegetarian pizzas.

Here is my current process:

```
def sort_pizzas(meats, pizzas):
    nonvegetarian_pizza_ids = []

    for pizza in pizzas:
        toppings = set(pizza.toppings.values_list('topping_name', flat=True))
        if any(map(toppings.__contains__, meats)):
            nonvegetarian_pizzas.append(pizza.id)
    return nonvegetarian_pizza_ids

def main():
    meats = ['pepperoni', 'ham', 'bacon', 'sausage']
    boatload_of_pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()

    nonvegetarian_pizza_ids = sort_pizzas(meats, boatload_of_pizzas)
```

This process is essentially forcing one of the waitstaff (cpu's) to sift through all of the pizzas by himself while the others get drunk on champagne and laugh at him.

My goal is to get all of my waitstaff working on this at the same time.

I'm trying to use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html) library of Python3, but can't seem to figure out whether/how I should use Pools, Managers, Pipes, Queues and the like to the greatest efficiency.

Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but generally I would try to rethink this approach before trying to make it incrementally faster (and much more complicated) with multiprocessing. For instance, it should be possible to do this with a single database query and offload all of the hard work to the database -- even easier if you can make "topping" objects aware of whether they are vegetarian or not (an extra boolean field on that table). Always try to simplify before optimizing! Also, mp efficiency gains evaporate in a Django app where you may have multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: My analogy breaks down a bit with this consideration, as in my particular scenario, the list of meats changes with each request.

Comment: That's still doable. Perhaps `Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__topping_name__in=meats)`. You pass the entire list of meat names into the database with the query, which is inelegant if the list is extremely large, but still better than trying to multiprocess.  Simple, readable code is more important than speed, and in this case you could easily be faster with the more straightforward code anyways.

Comment: Err, my mistake -- obviously the above should be `exclude()` instead of `filter()` if you want the pizzas WITHOUT meats as specified.

Comment: I would change the function signature from `sort_pizzas(meats, pizzas) -> nonvegan` to `partition_pizzas(pizzas, meats) -> (nonvegan, vegan)`

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, you can't follow [@Andrew Gorcester advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255052/python3-django-using-multiprocessing-to-build-a-common-list#comment33802139_22255052) then here's how you could parallize the partition of pizzas into two sets: vegeterian, nonvegeterian:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def is_vegetarian(pizza, meats):
    toppings = set(pizza.toppings.values_list('topping_name', flat=True))
    return pizza, not any(map(toppings.__contains__, meats))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    vegan, nonvegan = [], []
    for pizza, is_vegan in pool.map(partial(is_vegetarian, meats=meats), 
                                    boatload_of_pizzas):  
        (vegan if is_vegan else nonvegan).append(pizza)
```

See [Filter a list into two parts](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201306/filter_a_list_into_two_parts.html).

If `is_vegetarian()` is a light-weight function then the `multiprocessing` variant may be actually slower than a sequential one in a single process.